# Get the preceding sibling value for 1st occurance of attribute

Tags: xslt-1.0

`<Assignment workingHours="2.5" effFrom="2016-06-07" />`
`<Assignment workingHours="2.5" effFrom="2018-11-07" />`
`<Assignment workingHours="1.8" effFrom="2009-05-01" />`
`<Assignment workingHours="3.7" effFrom="2002-06-12" />`
`<Assignment workingHours="2.5" effFrom="2003-08-07" />`
`<Assignment workingHours="3.7" effFrom="2007-03-011" />`

I'm new to XSLT. I'm using XSLT 1.0 and need to parse through the input XML above and find the 1st occurance of attribute @workingHours = 3.7 and then get the value of the preceding attribute @effFrom.

So from the above example, I need to get the value @effFrom = 2009-05-01 using XSLT 1.0

I have a new requirement:
I need to parse through the above sample xml and find the 1st occurance of EITHER attribute @workingHours = 3.7 OR attribute @workingHours = 1.8, whichever comes 1st in the xml and then get the value of the preceding attribute @effFrom.

So from the above example, I need to get the value @effFrom = 2018-11-07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following xpath

```
//Assignment[@workingHours = '3.7'][1]/preceding-sibling::Assignment[1]/@effFrom
```

The usage depends on your need but you could make e.g. this

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Assignment[@workingHours = '3.7'][1]/preceding-sibling::Assignment[1]/@effFrom" />
```

Edit: for the later request a small change of xpath should work

```
//Assignment[@workingHours = '3.7' or @workingHours = '1.8'][1]/preceding-sibling::Assignment[1]/@effFrom
```

I.e.: `//Assignment[@workingHours = '3.7' or @workingHours = '1.8']` will select all Assignment element with @workingHours = 3.7 or 1.8. The second predicate `[1]` will select the first one from these Assignment elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jirka. I am trying to get this value in a variable and would use it in a function elsewhere. This is the piece i wrote in xsl  <xsl:variable name="contChangeDate">
  <xsl:for-each select="s1:Assignment">
   <xsl:value-of select="//Assignment[@workingHours = '3.70'][1]/preceding-sibling::Assignment[1]/@effFrom" />
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>    But i'm getting error : warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
error CS0103: The name 'effFrom' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Try it without the for-each. If it doesn't work anyway then edit your question and add your whole xslt into it as well as complete input xml.

Comment: @user2725668 given the `s1:` in your for-each select, I suspect your real document uses namespaces, and you'll need to use the same `s1` prefix in Jirka's XPath, i.e. `//s1:Assignment[@workingHourse = '3.7'][1]/preceding-sibling::s1:Assignment[1]/@effFrom`

Comment: Sorry.. the error: "The name 'effFrom' does not exist in the current context" was due to a silly mistake i did elsewhere in the xslt. I rectified that and added s1 prefix in Jirka's path. But now i am getting null value as output.

Comment: As far as I cannot see your source code it is hard to say where the problem could be.

Comment: It was my bad.. I had done some mistakes..sorry.. Your pice of code is working perfectly now. I'm getting the desired result. Thanks Jirka !

Comment: Hi Jirka... Could you please suggest a solution to my problem. I have edited the question

Comment: It should be an easy thing - look at improved answer.